# Proper way to use predicate in conditional variable

Tags: c++, multithreading, lambda, predicate, condition-variable

I want to know if I need to reset the predicate boolean variable inside the scope of the locked mutex. Right now, I have a std::unique_lock with a lambda function as the predicate parameter - The lambda function returns a boolean flag. Does this mean I need to set the boolean flag back to false inside the scope of the lock guard?

It seems to work a lot faster if I **don't** reset the boolean flag, but I'm not sure if this is the safe way to approach this.

```
#include <thread>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <mutex>

std::condition_variable _conditional;
bool processed = false;
std::mutex _mutex;

void Worker() {
    while (true) {
        //Doing other things ..
        //
        {
            //mutating shared data
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> _lock(_mutex);
            _conditional.wait(_lock, [] { return processed; });
            processed = false? //do I set this boolean back to false or just leave as is?
            data++;
        }
    }
}

void Reader() {
   //just prints out the changed data
    while (true) {
        std::cout << data << std::endl;
        processed = true;
        _conditional.notify_one();
    }

}

int main(){

   std::thread t1(Worked);
   std::thread t2(Reader);

   t1.join();
   t2.join();

}
```

Comment: That's a question for the one who designed this setup. What is the purpose of the boolean flag? What should cause it to be set to `true`? What should cause it to be set to `false`? Or perhaps: What does a `false` value represent? What does a `true` value represent?

Comment: @JaMiT `true` would represent that I just finished reading from the shared data, and that the `Worker()` thread is now able to mutate it, thus notifying worker thread with `.notify_one()` that it can now proceed to locking and changing the shared data.  I guess where I'm confused is that I don't know if I even **need** to change it back to `false`? since it will still run (faster) without changing it back to `false`. Does this mean the worker thread doesn't even wait since the flag is always true regardless if `.notify_one()` is called or not?

Comment: If you pull in too many implications, you're likely to confuse yourself. Try *"`true` would represent that I just finished reading from the shared data, and that the `Worker()` thread is now able to mutate it"* **full stop.** Don't go into what *happens* when the flag is `true`; just look at what that value *represents*. A `true` value means that `data` has been read and is ready to be processed. Short, sweet, and able to be negated: a `false` value then means that either `data` has not been read yet or that `data` is not to be processed. Which of these holds when `_lock` goes out of scope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, the `Reader` never acquires a lock to synchronize its access to the shared data (in this case the `processed` boolean and the `data` variable, whatever it is) with the `Worker`. As such, the `Reader` can modify `processed` while the `Worker` is reading from it, and the `Reader` can read from `data` while the `Worker` is writing to it; these are both race conditions. They can be fixed by having the `Reader` also lock the mutex before modifying `processed` or reading from `data`. The rest of this answer assumes that this correction is made.

Secondly, whether or not `processed` should be reset back to false is dependent on what you want the application to do, so it's necessary to understand the consequences.

If it is never reset to false, then the `Worker` will never again wait on the condition variable (though it will continuously reacquire the mutex and check the value of `processed`, despite the fact that it is *guaranteed* to be true after the first wait terminates), and it will simply keep incrementing `data`. Even if you correctly synchronize access to the shared data like I mentioned, this still might not do what you want it to do. It's very possible that the `Worker` could acquire the mutex several times in a row before the `Reader`, and thus `data` can be incremented multiple times in-between prints, *and* `data` can be printed multiple times in-between increments (there is *no* order guarantee for printing and incrementing, in such a case)

If you reset `processed` back to false after each wait within the `Worker`, then you can guarantee that `data` will be printed *at least* once in-between each increment, since it would be unable to increment `data` until the `Reader` has notified it (which requires at least one print first). However, it may still be printed multiple times in-between each increment, because there is still no mechanism forcing the `Reader` to wait on the `Worker`.

If you provide another mechanism allowing the `Reader` to also wait on the `Worker`, then you can theoretically guarantee that each print happens exactly once in-between each increment (alternating). But once you've gone this far, the entire process is run serially, so there's really no point in using multiple threads anymore.

Notice that each of these approaches all have entirely different semantics. The one you should choose depends on what you want your application to do.

Comment: And obviously, if you don't want your application to do any of these things, you should probably come up with a different, appropriate solution.

Comment: Thank you for the answer with all of the design implications. This is exactly what I was wondering.